# Stateful Testing gives up halfway and restarts from the beginning

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I am writing a test using Stateful Testing feature of hypothesis.

I am finding out that after a certain number of state changes, the testing restarts from the beginning.

How can I make it continue along existing path?

I have set `max_examples=1` and `stateful_step_count=999999` but that does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Occasional restarts are an intentional feature of stateful tests, and must be possible for us to present a minimal (fewest steps) counterexample if your test fails.

In your specific case, I suspect that the statemachine is 'getting stuck' and having to retry some steps.  Because it could not complete `max_step` steps, it may not count as an example for `max_examples`!

For more detailed comments, I'd have to see your actual code and an example output :-)